# How to prove Big O notation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, theorem-proving

In my algorithm class we are discussing big O notation and I am stuck proving this example problem:

Prove `f(n) = 3n lg n + 10n + lg n + 20 = O(n lg n)`

Details will be appreciated.

Comment: 4 n lg n > f(n) > 3 n lg n

Comment: @Beta can you explain in details?

Comment: Yes. How much of it can you do on your own?

Comment: Isn't this *math* instead of *programming*?  It smells off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Big O` notation is an *asymptotic notation* and it's all about approximation of cases (worst, best and mid one).
In your example, `nlgn` grows faster than both `n` and `lgn`, moreover constant values are not relevant and can be ignored in such an approximation.
Because of that, it follows that the complexity is `O(nlgn)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to prove is that for some M and X0:
M n lg n >= 3n lg n +10n + lg n + 20 for all n greater than X0

4 is pretty easy for M

I'm sure you can compute some x0 for which the above inequality holds and then easily show that it remains true for all n greater than X0

It helps to simplify the above after substituting in the 4 to
(n-1)lg n >= 10n + 20

Once any n is big enough, it should be clear that lg n > 1, so any increase in n beyond that increase the right by 1 and the left by more than 1.

Comment: No, you also have to prove that f(n) > N n lg n for all n >X0.

Comment: @Beta, not according to Wikipedia (It gives rules based on O() setting only an upper bound not upper and lower).

Comment: By that reasoning, g(n)=n is also O(n lg n).

Comment: @Beta That is correct.  f(n)=n is O(n lg n) and f(n)=n is also O(n).  Try reading a definition rather than asserting what you imagined from the context of typical use.

Comment: I am shocked to find that you're right; what I thought was big O is actually big Theta.